# could I group rows related to the same id to remove nulls and put all related data in the same row?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, null

I have this data set

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kRQb.png)4

And the desired result should be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31KGb.png)

I tried with group by and row_number() but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) *"I tried with group by and row_number() but it didn't work as expected."* And what were those attempts? Why didn't they work (as expected)?

Comment: What if you have multiple unique values in one of the columns? Please be more specific about the logic.

Comment: may use [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) instead images

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

aggregate function such as `Max`, `string_agg` works well with `null values` and can mask them easily. use following query

```
select 
max(seq) seq,
max(code) code,
max(codeType) codeType,
max(codeDesc) codeDesc,
max(number) number
from 
yourtable
```